# How to go doc a package from the web?

Tags: go

I can not check the doc for the following package.

```
$ go version
go version go1.16 darwin/amd64
$ go get golang.org/x/net/icmp
$ go doc golang.org/x/net/icmp
doc: no required module provides package golang.org/x/net/icmp: working directory is not part of a module
exit status 1
```

But I can check the doc for the following package.

```
$ go doc net | head -n 1
package net // import "net"
```

How to check the doc of a remote package? Thanks.

Comment: To read documentation with the `go doc` command, use the `go get` command to fetch the package locally.  Use [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/) to read package documentation on the web. The documentation for golang.org/x/net/icmp is available at https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/icmp.

Comment: I did it already `go get golang.org/x/net/icmp`. It didn't work. Did you try it on your own?

Comment: If you are running go 1.16, then you either need to disable module more or change directory to the module where you executed `go get`.

Comment: Could you show me the exact sequence of commands so that `go doc` will work? What is special about go 1.16?

Comment: Modules are enabled by default in Go 1.16.  Option1: Disable modules: `GO111MODULE=off go get golang.org/x/net/icmp; GO111MODULE=off go doc golang.org/x/net/icmp`  Option 2: Use modules.  Change your working directory to a directory in a module and issue the commands shown in the question.

Comment: So there is a big change between Go 1.16 and Go 1.15. I used to have Go 1.15 if I remember it correctly. At that time, `go get golang.org/x/net/icmp` can download the files to `~/go/src/`. But in Go 1.16, the same command does download the files to ~/go/src. Do you know what is wrong?